# Symfony 4.4 - Custom Error Templates Not Working

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.4

I've got an issue when it comes to using Custom Error Templates in Symfony 4.4 Flex. Everything has been set properly according to the guide from https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller/error_pages.html

I **can** access the Custom Error Templates via `/_error/{errorCode}` when I run the application with `APP_ENV=dev` - but if I change `APP_ENV` to **prod** (with `APP_DEBUG` set to **false/0** of course), I get the default Symfony "500 Internal Server Error" page. I even tested it after deploying the application on the remote host, and it's the same issue when I try to access /random-unexisting-page (already got the error404.html.twig template set and it works on 'dev' via /_error/404).

I want to know, does it have anything to do with other configuration within /config/ ? Have you got any idea what the issue could be ?

Comment: I suggest you create a small reproducer app and report it to the Symfony repo. It's hard to know what is missing on your side without more information.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few tries and I think I've understood your problem.

So when you want to create a personalized error page, first you need to add, under the template directory, the following path, same as your link said

```
templates/
└─ bundles/
   └─ TwigBundle/
      └─ Exception/
         ├─ error404.html.twig
         ├─ error403.html.twig
         └─ error.html.twig      # All other HTML errors (including 500)
```

The most common error is the 500 so you can add this: `error500.html.twig` or just leave the generic one, it's up to you.

The importamt thing is that **whenever** you add a file error in the directory or you simply make a change in an existing file: you **MUST** launch the command to clear the cache (**you can only launch this command when the project has no errors**). If you don’t do this the changes wont be visualized.

STEPS:

- fix the error or start from a previous working build
- launch the clear command: `php bin\console cache:clear`,
  you'll get something like that [result_of_clear_cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7URP.png)
- refresh the page and you should see the new page

PS. if you need some visual references:

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REUOB.png)

[error_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t5SD.png)

[result_on_browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi1q8.png)